# Understanding spamassassin and its scoring

Tags: exim, spamassassin

I'm trying to figure out why a lot of my emails are being treated as spam. The setup is Exim4, Dovecot and SpamAssassin. Here is am example email that arrives at the inbox:

```
Return-path: <andy.newby@gmail.com>
Envelope-to: bob@start-eng.co.uk
Delivery-date: Thu, 01 Jun 2017 13:01:35 +0100
Received: from mail-wr0-f171.google.com ([209.85.128.171])
    by admin.newbyhost.com with esmtps (TLS1.2:ECDHE_RSA_AES_128_GCM_SHA256:128)
    (Exim 4.86_2)
    (envelope-from <andy.newby@gmail.com>)
    id 1dGOnH-0002Qk-88
    for bob@start-eng.co.uk; Thu, 01 Jun 2017 13:01:35 +0100
Received: by mail-wr0-f171.google.com with SMTP id v104so6526226wrb.0
        for <bob@start-eng.co.uk>; Thu, 01 Jun 2017 05:01:35 -0700 (PDT)
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed;
        d=gmail.com; s=20161025;
        h=mime-version:reply-to:from:date:message-id:subject:to;
        bh=+UNmwam33KPk4JxoT31uL7p6g75CgwyhNIl2HRp+UHc=;
        b=YF8QfeQ5JLTeWkc86CyuB0izOBh5zWc2bT1cjdqfbeNAzWcKVNNGvWouHqwJj5nFhm
         tGZiy36zP/qjSltEtmtSTK+RtF8o7FlFFSPjxtzWbnRr1Uv2pNdkSdcz3hNkGF62e6CZ
         M52lko32sFa/nd8kYQhPF9XtKed88oa4MxEoPgumgn2i66uu4ZL/mvVuKY9IQTugFM3M
         0DFmWDn1utgEcJcYkybA6BKhtlQLDcpTG83d2BRjN2L7mEbtuXBt6J/5USzHMC8TmLPh
         ukQ7nJo4OlIyNboKBLMMlfRBrbqUeQFQCf0ahtTD/iU0468unM+2ykcSU3KC/vnXwAVH
         EPnA==
X-Google-DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed;
        d=1e100.net; s=20161025;
        h=x-gm-message-state:mime-version:reply-to:from:date:message-id
         :subject:to;
        bh=+UNmwam33KPk4JxoT31uL7p6g75CgwyhNIl2HRp+UHc=;
        b=pw9PFq5poRdO1ZVTaMo1Kyx3MBBgbD8GR+PefSFv7BLAqwL6Ra1R7vCvRqaYiSZbCw
         M4Mvbt20/wP+GpZJZcFicR6Q6oNZbfIq5+jHXc6COgogNq75mg5NKb6UVyooBSKDvxRQ
         sJQMrCdQdf3QvoJq4njRi3o0M+KbF70KbstVsBEzzcwt8WqWgAxO97weWEC9Loo3wgpU
         HeOMBDx2PJHTwJY7o7IDmtUG+3LW32TbkRudWa2J18mFcBXThQOLTHriDZn23N3Y0DJN
         Si0VIM6zlhy0F9XoqKykkkbprY+g+FVlFo1RADGDvbgiSXUfYRYLY8yeFFYe2rdncGdl
         XEBA==
X-Gm-Message-State: AODbwcCRSTYCmq3V0QXqzVn1SnIoUcklbBtHZ7nwT7P8Y0R6IaI6isx7
    Fe2D8EAL7XgI2nLsOdApo8CMw6TTSQ==
X-Received: by 10.223.134.46 with SMTP id 43mr1190589wrv.123.1496318488607;
 Thu, 01 Jun 2017 05:01:28 -0700 (PDT)
MIME-Version: 1.0
Received: by 10.223.172.20 with HTTP; Thu, 1 Jun 2017 05:01:08 -0700 (PDT)
Reply-To: andy.newby@gmail.com
From: Andy Newby <andy.newby@gmail.com>
Date: Thu, 1 Jun 2017 13:01:08 +0100
Message-ID: <CALvgFsuZG24KsNqAShA5mgcwZYNEpaGyNdoMohe0RhYA8dx9gw@mail.gmail.com>
To: bob <bob@start-eng.co.uk>
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="001a1146b7bcfc00300550e4cbcd"
X-Spam-Score: 14
X-Spam-Bar: +
X-Spam-Report: Spam detection software, running on the system "admin.newbyhost.com",
 has NOT identified this incoming email as spam.  The original
 message has been attached to this so you can view it or label
 similar future email.  If you have any questions, see
 @@CONTACT_ADDRESS@@ for details.

 Content preview:  test Andy Newby *Email:* andy@ultranerds.co.uk *WWW: *http://www.ultranerds.co.uk
    *Mobile: * 07769 201 576 test [...] 

 Content analysis details:   (1.4 points, 5.0 required)

  pts rule name              description
 ---- ---------------------- --------------------------------------------------
  0.0 URIBL_BLOCKED          ADMINISTRATOR NOTICE: The query to URIBL was blocked.
                             See
                             http://wiki.apache.org/spamassassin/DnsBlocklists#dnsbl-block
                              for more information.
                             [URIs: docs.google.com]
 -0.2 RCVD_IN_MSPIKE_H2      RBL: Average reputation (+2)
                             [209.85.128.171 listed in wl.mailspike.net]
 -0.0 RCVD_IN_DNSWL_NONE     RBL: Sender listed at http://www.dnswl.org/, no
                             trust
                             [209.85.128.171 listed in list.dnswl.org]
 -0.0 SPF_PASS               SPF: sender matches SPF record
  0.0 FREEMAIL_FROM          Sender email is commonly abused enduser mail provider
                             (andy.newby[at]gmail.com)
  0.0 HTML_MESSAGE           BODY: HTML included in message
  1.6 HTML_IMAGE_ONLY_12     BODY: HTML: images with 800-1200 bytes of words
  0.0 T_DKIM_INVALID         DKIM-Signature header exists but is not valid
  0.0 T_REMOTE_IMAGE         Message contains an external image
X-Spam-Status: Yes
X-ACL-Warn: SpamAssassin detected spam (from andy.newby@gmail.com to bob@start-eng.co.uk).
Subject: *** SPAM *** test

--001a1146b7bcfc00300550e4cbcd
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8"

test

Andy Newby
*Email:*    andy@ultranerds.co.uk
*WWW:    *http://www.ultranerds.co.uk
*Mobile: * 07769 201 576

--001a1146b7bcfc00300550e4cbcd
Content-Type: text/html; charset="UTF-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

<div dir=3D"ltr">test<div><br clear=3D"all"><div><div class=3D"gmail_signat=
ure" data-smartmail=3D"gmail_signature"><div dir=3D"ltr"><div><div dir=3D"l=
tr"><div><div dir=3D"ltr"><div><div dir=3D"ltr">Andy Newby=C2=A0<div><font =
size=3D"1"><b>Email:</b>=C2=A0 =C2=A0=C2=A0<a href=3D"mailto:andy@ultranerd=
s.co.uk" target=3D"_blank">andy@ultranerds.co.uk</a>=C2=A0</font></div><div=
><b><span style=3D"font-size:x-small">WWW:</span><span style=3D"font-size:x=
-small">=C2=A0 =C2=A0=C2=A0</span></b><a href=3D"http://www.ultranerds.co.u=
k" style=3D"font-size:x-small" target=3D"_blank">http://www.ultranerds.co.u=
k</a><span style=3D"font-size:x-small"> =C2=A0</span></div><div><b style=3D=
"font-size:x-small">Mobile:=C2=A0</b><span style=3D"font-size:x-small">=C2=
=A007769 201 576</span><div><div><img src=3D"https://docs.google.com/uc?exp=
ort=3Ddownload&amp;id=3D0B2xS_1XN-aUHT2lBdXlSOFVFM2M&amp;revid=3D0B2xS_1XN-=
aUHTUNrb0JVVHY5Q0lwb0h0czY4QlRaYW5pOWp3PQ" style=3D"font-size:12.8px"><br><=
/div></div></div><div><br></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div><=
/div></div>
</div></div>

--001a1146b7bcfc00300550e4cbcd--
```

It has 2 totally conflicting scores, and I'm not sure why :/

```
X-Spam-Score: 14
X-Spam-Bar: +
```

...and then below that:

```
 Content analysis details:   (1.4 points, 5.0 required)
```

And due to the fact `X-Spam-Status:` is `Yes` (due to the 14 score, and my threshold is 10), it gets rewritten and moved into my spam box. I really don't get what is going on

In /etc/exim4/exim4.conf.template ,I have this rule set:

```
SPAMASSASSIN = yes
SPAM_SCORE = 10

system_filter = /etc/exim4/system.filter
system_filter_user = Debian-exim
```

...and then this rule in **/etc/exim4/system.filter**:

```
if $h_X-Spam-Status: contains "Yes"
then
    headers add "Old-Subject: $h_subject"
    headers remove "Subject"
    headers add "Subject: *** SPAM *** $h_old-subject"
    headers remove "Old-Subject"
endif
```

**UPDATE:** As requested, here is the output from **/var/log/mail.log**:

```
Jun  1 13:55:40 admin spamd[3850]: spamd: connection from localhost [127.0.0.1]:45126 to port 783, fd 6
Jun  1 13:55:40 admin spamd[3850]: spamd: setuid to debian-spamd succeeded
Jun  1 13:55:40 admin spamd[3850]: spamd: checking message <CALvgFst0Sw_pMpaByZYZ0iv8+uXhUZKwBt14u4Nuxq+dFTJFKg@mail.gmail.com> for debian-spamd:114
Jun  1 13:55:41 admin spamd[3850]: spamd: clean message (1.6/5.0) for debian-spamd:114 in 0.2 seconds, 3924 bytes.
Jun  1 13:55:41 admin spamd[3850]: spamd: result: . 1 - FREEMAIL_FROM,HTML_IMAGE_ONLY_12,HTML_MESSAGE,RCVD_IN_DNSWL_NONE,RCVD_IN_MSPIKE_H3,RCVD_IN_MSPIKE_WL,SPF_PASS,T_DKIM_INVALID,T_REMOTE_IMAGE,URIBL_BLOCKED scantime=0.2,size=3924,user=debian-spamd,uid=114,required_score=5.0,rhost=localhost,raddr=127.0.0.1,rport=45126,mid=<CALvgFst0Sw_pMpaByZYZ0iv8+uXhUZKwBt14u4Nuxq+dFTJFKg@mail.gmail.com>,autolearn=no autolearn_force=no
Jun  1 13:55:41 admin spamd[3670]: prefork: child states: II
^X^C
```

...and then **/var/log/exim4/mainlog**:

```
2017-06-01 13:55:40 1dGPdc-0004Pc-Uq DKIM: d=gmail.com s=20161025 c=relaxed/relaxed a=rsa-sha256 [verification succeeded]
2017-06-01 13:55:41 1dGPdc-0004Pc-Uq <= andy.newby@gmail.com H=mail-wm0-f45.google.com [74.125.82.45] P=esmtps X=TLS1.2:ECDHE_RSA_AES_128_GCM_SHA256:128 CV=no S=5747 id=CALvgFst0Sw_pMpaByZYZ0iv8+uXhUZKwBt14u4Nuxq+dFTJFKg@mail.gmail.com
2017-06-01 13:55:41 1dGPdc-0004Pc-Uq => info <info@start-eng.co.uk> R=localuser_spam T=local_spam_delivery
2017-06-01 13:55:41 1dGPdc-0004Pc-Uq Completed
```

Comment: There isn't enough information. Could you add lines from your mail logs regarding the same message?

Comment: @EsaJokinen Thanks for the reply. I've added the output of 2 of the logs. Please let me know if there are others I should be looking at?

Comment: The current log lines are consistent with the `X-Spam-Report`. I have a hunch there's another instance of SpamAssassin the mail goes through. Your logs are incomplete: these line only shows what happens inside the (working) `spamd`. I'd like to know the whole flow through the mail server from arriving to the final delivery to the mailbox.

Comment: What is goign on with your DKIM stuff?  `DKIM-Signature header exists but is not valid` - this may be the cause

Comment: @EsaJokinen - I'm not sure how to work out what else is going on? I'm still a bit of a server newbie (no pun intended ;))

Comment: @ivanivan - I'm not sure. That is the gmail DKIM sig, not my end. I also can't work out why I get: `The query to URIBL was blocked.`. The server only gets about 1000 emails a day, yet it always seems to have that message in the reports

Comment: *"The query to URIBL was blocked"*  - Typically that happens when you don't run your own resolver but use your ISP's or for instance Google's 8.8.8.8 public DNS servers. (run your own resolver and point `/etc/resolv.conf` name-server entry to localhost)

Comment: @HBruijn - thanks. I'm on linode, and that file has: https://pastebin.com/Ly0kArVZ . I'm not too sure how/if I can do that with Linode?

Comment: Please, show the section of exim config where the spam assassin's check is configured.

Comment: @AndrewNewby linode will let you do your own dns.  Simply install the default bind9 package and change /etc/resolv.conf to have only the line `nameserver 127.0.0.1` in it

Answer (score 0):

1. On that SpamAssassin report you can see your IP it's listed on 2 RBLS (mailspike.net and dnswl.org). Check those sites to see how you can get removed.
2. The Spam Score 10 on config file it's translated to spam level 1.0 which it's very very low, usually 5.0 it's when a message gets marked as spam. Change the /etc/exim4/exim4.conf.template spam score to 50 or more.
3. Run your domain on https://intodns.com/ to see mail related problems which can get you listed on RBLS.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a mixup between `$spam_score` and `$spam_score_int` in your exim configuration.

From [the relevant exim documentation chapter](https://www.exim.org/exim-html-current/doc/html/spec_html/ch-content_scanning_at_acl_time.html) (emphasis mine):

> $spam_score
>
> The spam score of the message, for example, “3.4” or “30.5”. This is useful for inclusion in log or reject messages.

> $spam_score_int
>
> The spam score of the message, **multiplied by ten, as an integer value**. For example “34” or “305”. It may appear to disagree with $spam_score because $spam_score is rounded and $spam_score_int is truncated. The integer value is useful for numeric comparisons in conditions.

I don't fully grasp your config, especially the `/etc/exim4/exim4.conf.template` file - it's probably debian and/or not up to the current exim config rules. But: `1.4` as in the report text looks a lot like it could be `14` when accessed via `$spam_score_int` variable!